# Geting error as Object reference not set to instance of an object when clicking save button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (!row.IsNewRow)

                {
                    string keyword = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    string fname = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    string comm = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    string retur = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    string message = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    string inm = this.cmbInNa.Text.ToString();
                    i = pbl.fsave(keyword, fname, comm, retur, message, inm);
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    }
                }                            
        }
    }
```

While clicking btnSave, I'm getting "object reference not set to instance of an object". I want to insert values in gridview. What is the issue?

Comment: What line are you getting your error on, try setting a break point and stepping through your logic

Comment: Try using `Convert.ToString();` instead of `ToString()` method, as ToString method throws the null pointer exception

Comment: use a debugger ... open the exceptions dialog (debug menu, exceptions ...) and set the mark in "common language runtime exceptions" ... then when the program breaks you can inspect your variables to SEE which one is null ... that's better than guessing ...

Answer (score 2):

Any of those grid cell value could be `null` applying `ToString()` on null values would result in exception.

```
string keyword = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Best way is to check for null before doing a ToString(). You could use a [Turnary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

```
string keyword = (null != row.Cells[0].Value) ? row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: i replaced my code with ur code AccessDenied, But its not working, while debugging it will again show null exception.

Comment: Can you copy **exact line** where its throwing exception ?

Comment: This solution works perfectly! +1 to both question and answer. It really saved my bacon.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with null exception, followed the hints given here, but have no null fields in the table.

The problem was, that I had disabled a button-column by removing the following line:

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(sense_button_Click);
```

So, to every button column, you HAVE to give an event handler, which can have no code. Otherwise you will get an exception from whatever you click on the table.